# Can spring sockjs be used with a container which does not support javax.websockets

Tags: spring, sockjs, spring-websocket

Can I use spring sockjs server with a container which does not implement javax.websockets such as websphere 8.5, this URL mentions https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-sockjs-protocol-webapp, but then my understanding was Spring will use its native implementation or just use one of comet techniques if websocket support is not available with comet

Answer (score 0):

It can be used, but it will fallback to comet implementation. 
Spring does NOT uses any native implementation for websocket - Got exception "No Request Upgrade Strategy found" in containers which do not support websockets (tomcat6, websphere) and it falls back to its COMET implementation